# Как залить проект с бд на гитхаб?

Tags: c#, .net, git, asp.net-mvc, github

Делаю проект asp.net core с бд, как мне залить проект в месте с бд() что-бы я мог его развернуть на другой машине??

Comment: а что делать с connectionString его придется на каждой машине менять?

Comment: Обычно саму бд с кодом не хранят. Вместо этого вы можете хранить миграции или скрипты для создания бд рядом с кодом. При таком сценарии вы на нужном окружении указываете строку подключения и запускаете проект, который сам автоматом создает бд и накатывает все нужные миграции.

Comment: а как в таком случае, в самом проекте запустить мой скрипт?

Comment: Ну вот например один из вариантов: https://github.com/jbogard/contosoUniversityDotNetCore-Pages возможно подойдёт.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то типа:

1. Создать репозиторий на гитхабе
2. Клонировать локально в пустую папку и перенести папку .git в папку проекта (альтернативно: [как клонировать в существующую папку](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2411031/5752652))
3. Создать в корневой папке проекта подходящий .gitignore (чтобы всякий хлам не затащить в проект)
4. Дать команды `git add .`, затем `git commit -m 'commit description'`и `git push`.

Всё! Можете переходить на другую машину и клонировать.

> а что делать с connectionString его придется на каждой машине менять?

Вводные слова: connectionString -- это часть окружения. Окружение -- это то, что у каждого своё. Идеально: вообще не складывать коннекшн стринги в гит.

Частный подход зависит от команды, от проекта. Можете положить в .gitignore этот файл, можете договориться что у всех в конфиге будет одинаковое имя базы и имя сервера (локалхост). В более крупных проектах это всё равно будет разворачиваться на прод из CI

> как мне залить проект *вместе с бд()*

Общий подход: данные — не код, БД — не код. Поэтому саму базу в гит стараются не складывать, хотя бывают проекты, где есть sql-скрипты инициализации самых основных справочников, без которых не стартануть.

А вот схема данных — это часть проекта, оформляйте в EF миграции ([пример](https://github.com/akmetainfo/WallyBackend/tree/master/src/Wally.Persistence/Migrations)), пишите скрипты накатывания миграций — и это вполне качественный подход к задаче.

Понимаете, на гитхаб обычно складывают демо-приложения, в них все настройки выставлены в некоторый дефолт, чтобы быстро можно было пощупать приложение: сервер -- `localhost` или `LocalDb\mssqllocaldb`, имя базы прописано, пользователь admin с каким-нибудь простым паролем указанным в документации...
И это неплохой подход, можете начать с такого.

В качестве ответа думаю пока хватит, дальше копайте отдельные вопросы глубже: у вас по факту не один вопрос, а сразу множество -- хотите проработать кучу аспектов, которые в общем-то за вас никто не выберет.

Comment: я знаю как работать с гитом, интересует бд

Comment: @KhmulkoPavel, для БД - экспорт дампа вашей базы, и потом импорт где надо

Comment: @KhmulkoPavel Если вы знаете, как работать с гит, но не написали об этом в вопросе -- то не жалуйтесь, что вокруг нет телепатов, которые об этом знают.

Comment: Правильно ли я понял, я заливаю свой проект на гит с дефолтным конфигом, и дампом бд, далее на другой машине, клонирую, импортирую дамп, и пишу свой connectionString?

Comment: Не привыкайте к плохому. Дампы баз никто не выкладывает в гит. Продакшн база может содержать гигабайты данных, меняться ежедневно -- но для разработки достаточно иметь схему/структуру базы в гите, тесты для того, чтобы прогнать типовые сценарии и так далее. Вы смешиваете три вопроса: версионное хранение кода должно быть отдельно, управление конфигурациями должно быть отдельно и управление данными должно быть отдельно. Не надо второй и третий вопрос решать при помощи гит.

Comment: Допустим у меня тестовое задание сделать проект asp.net core с бд соотвественно, в бд минимальное кол-во данных чисто для теста правильно ли работает прога, я должен залить на гит и отправить проверяющему, который должен приложить минимальные усилие дабы развернуть мой проект с моей бд

Comment: @KhmulkoPavel Для начала стоит ли уточнить, есть ли у разработчика visual studio, а то может он сам накатит схему базы через Update-Database и запустит install.sql который добавит пользователя базы. Возможно использовать [OnModelCreating / seeds database](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding) когда вы заполните базу парой строк при развёртывании с нуля. Вариантов масса. У вас по факту не один вопрос, а сразу множество -- хотите проработать кучу аспектов, которые в общем-то за вас никто не выберет.

Comment: @AK окей, как насчет такого, сгенерирую два скрипта (на создание и заполнение бд) и в readme напишу что для начала нужно запустить два эти два скрипта, затем поменять connectionString

Comment: @KhmulkoPavel В принципе, нормально. Но если у вас есть проверяющий -- то это лучше у него уточнить/согласовать с ним.